# How To Convert HTML to PDF using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html-to-pdf

I want to convert HTML to PDF with the click of a button and download.
My js working perfectly only need the latest JavaScript CDN link.

**HTML**

```
<div id="pageprint">
   <div id="reportbox">Hello World!!</div>
</div> 
<button type="button" onclick="downloadCode();">Download HTML</button>
```

**Javascript**

```
<script>
    function generatePDF() {
    
    const element = document.getElementById("pageprint");
    document.getElementById("reportbox").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("reportbox").style.marginTop = "0px"; 
    document.getElementById("pageprint").style.border = "1px solid black";
    html2pdf().from(element).save('download.pdf'); 
    }
    
    function downloadCode(){
    var x = document.getElementById("reportbox");  
    generatePDF();
    setTimeout(function() { window.location=window.location;},3000);}
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, My js working perfectly only need the latest JavaScript CDN link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you need is the CDN then simply add it after the `</body>`

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2pdf.js/0.10.1/html2pdf.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha512-GsLlZN/3F2ErC5ifS5QtgpiJtWd43JWSuIgh7mbzZ8zBps+dvLusV+eNQATqgA/HdeKFVgA5v3S/cIrLF7QnIg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

```js
    function generatePDF() {
    
    const element = document.getElementById("pageprint");
    document.getElementById("reportbox").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("reportbox").style.marginTop = "0px"; 
    document.getElementById("pageprint").style.border = "1px solid black";
    html2pdf().from(element).save('download.pdf'); 
    }
    
    function downloadCode(){
    var x = document.getElementById("reportbox");  
    generatePDF();
    setTimeout(function() { window.location=window.location;},3000);}
```

```html
<div id="pageprint">
   <div id="reportbox">Hello World!!</div>
</div> 
<button type="button" onclick="downloadCode();">Download HTML</button>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2pdf.js/0.10.1/html2pdf.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

However seems a very odd way to ask a user to download a pdf page since the option disappears after the download is attempted, so change of mind does not keep it user visible to try differently on fail.
[image]

So for example, I say open the download on current page, I see
[image]

but if I say open in PDF Viewer I see
[image]

It's much simpler to layout the printable HTML page as text not image, and suggest the user prints or saves exactly as their browser is configured and their desire, best result for all, especially as no libraries are needed.
Nor will the page be cluttered by buttons.
[image]

Comment: The only problem is that it's really blurry and looks like a image

Answer (score 1):

There isn't an easy way to do this. The best thing you could do is to open an empty page, fill it with your html data and print it to pdf. Or look for some external libary like jsPDF.

example for print to pdf:

```js
 var wnd = window.open('about:blank', '', '_blank');
 wnd.document.write("<p> Some HTML-Content </p> ");
 wnd.print();
```

Answer (score -1):

You can print html just as follow.

```
<style type="text/css">
    @media print{ button {display:none} };
</style>

<div id="pageprint">
   <div id="reportbox">Hello World!!</div>
</div> 
<button type="button" onclick=javascript:window.print()>Download HTML</button>
```

Please let me know if any issue found

Comment: The questioner want to convert html into pdf format. The browser doesn't provide pdf format by default.

Comment: Thank you for the help, My js working perfectly only need the latest JavaScript CDN link.